# Unison sync getting copy of replaced files

Tags: unison

I'm facing very serious issue. I have configured unison for synchronising file among servers. It takes copy of a file from server-1 and replace or copy file to other servers. I have added a folder directly on server-2 and server-1(base server) had old copy files and folder. After synchronising all of my files to server-2 replaced by older files from server-1. Is there any way to recover files from server-2? Does unison itself maintains a version control or backup?

Answer (score 0):

Unison does not maintain a backup of synced files by default. You have to add some backup settings to your unison profile to enable backups. Something like:

```
backuplocation = central
backupdir = /path/to/central/backups
backup = Name * 
backupcurr = Name *
backupsuffix = .$VERSION
```

In this case you will have to use other data recovery techniques to try to restore your files.